What is the cardinality of the set of paths in the plane?
What is the cardinality of the set of paths in the plane?
In the question Can you explicitly write R^2 as a disjoint union of totally path disconnected sets, Eric Wofsey describes in a comment a partition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into two totally path-disconnected sets. That comment seems to imply that the cardinality of the set of paths in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $|\mathbb{R}|$. How do you show that?

A path, being a continuous map $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$, is uniquely determined by its values at rational points in $[0, 1]$...

Hah, I guess there are only so many ways to say that!

A path is compact, hence closed. Since $\mathbb R$ is second countable, it has (at most) $2^{\aleph_0}$ many open sets.

A path is a map $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is continuous. A continuous map is determined by its values at rational points. So you only need countably many values per path to define the path. So a path is defined by a pair of endpoints and a countable number of points on the path, which means there are $|\mathbb{R}^2|^2 \times |\mathbb{R}^2|^{|\mathbb{N}|} = |\mathbb{R}|$ of them. ($|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}| = |(2^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}}| = |2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}| = |2^{\mathbb{N}}| = |\mathbb{R}|$.)
